# Cannot GET /users/test nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to load /users/(username) for specific user profile pages, however I'm getting a `Cannot GET /users/test` error. I had it working at one point but then I added a function and it's broken again (I'm thinking the problem may be there in the route). Here's the relevant files. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

app.js:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const _ = require('lodash');
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const exphbs = require('express-handlebars');
const expressValidator = require('express-validator');
const flash = require('connect-flash');
const session = require('express-session');
const passport = require('passport');
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
const mongo = require('mongodb');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/tipcup');
var db = mongoose.connection;

const routes = require('./routes/index');
const users = require('./routes/users');
const user = require('./routes/user');

// Init App
var app = express();

// View Engine
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.engine('handlebars', exphbs({defaultLayout: 'layout'}));
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');

// BodyParser middleware
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false}));
app.use(cookieParser());

// Set Static Folder
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// Express Session
app.use(session({
  secret: 'secret',
  saveUninitialized: true,
  resave: true
}));

// Passport Init
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

// Express Validator
app.use(expressValidator ({
  errorFormatter: function(param, msg, value) {
    var namespace = param.split('.')
    , root = namespace.shift()
    , formParam = root;

    while(namespace.length){
      formParam += '[' + namespace.shift() + ']';
    }
    return {
      param: formParam,
      msg: msg,
      value: value
    };
  }
}));

// Connect Flash
app.use(flash());

// Global Vars
app.use(function (req, res, next){
  res.locals.success_msg = req.flash('success_msg');
  res.locals.error_msg = req.flash('error_msg');
  res.locals.error = req.flash('error');
  res.locals.user = req.user || null;
  next();
});

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);
app.use('/user/:username', user);

// Set Port
app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 3000));

app.listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log('Server started on port '+app.get('port'));
});
```

user.js route:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var User = require('../models/user');

// GET user by username
router.get('/:username', function(req, res) {
  //var username = req.params.username;
  User.getUserByUsername(function(err, user) {

    if(err) {
        res.send('error');
        next();
    }

    const vm = user;
    res.render('user', vm);

  });
  //res.render('user');
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Can you narrow down to a [MCVE]? Also, what error is that line actually producing, if any? What did your `GET` look like when it was working? What function did you add? Can you narrow down the problem to one file?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I added the `User.getUserByUsername` function inside the `router.get('/:username...etc` router function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its looks like you are defining the User Id twice

In `app.js` you are mounting the users routes `/user/:username` with the line

`app.use('/user/:username', user);`

Then in `user.js` you are declaring the get to `/:username` with the line

`router.get('/:username', function(req, res) {`

I would think this would produce a route with the signature `/user/:username/:username`

I would suggest remove the `/:username` one of the files

Comment: Thanks for the reply! This fixed the problem. I removed :username from app.js and kept it in the user.js route file, works great now!

Comment: Great!  Happy to help

Answer (score 1):

```
router.get('/:username', function(req, res) {
      var username = req.params.username;

      User.getUserByUsername(username).then(function(err, user){
        res.json(user);
      });
```

for mongoose you can do this:

```
router.get('/:username', function(req, res) {
      var username = req.params.username;

      User.getUserByUsername(username,function(err, user){
        res.json(user);
      });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I still seem to be getting the same error after making the change

Comment: I used the answer above to fix the issue, but your queries were a big help and helped me figure out how to use mongoose better! Thank you so much!